# How to change particular index image in flatlist renderitem react native on conditional

Tags: react-native, audio-player, react-native-flatlist

I am showing some Audio data in Flat-list. Flat-list, I am showing in main class, But, RenderItem calling in separate class. So, Once I tapped particular row item, I am playing audio file. But, I have to change pause to play image. But, When I tried to change it, All images are getting changes.
Bydefault, I am showing all cells images with pause icon.

Also Once user taps on play/pause in audio player, Then I have to change flatlist current playing item row images either play/pause.

I am showing audio player in bottom of the screen. Once user tap on flatlist pause icon, I am playing audio player in bottom of the screen.

I have tired but, All cells images getting changing.
Any suggestions?

Note: We have different UI for Audio player,  So,  I have created customized UI for player instead of default media component.

Main class.js

```
  selectedAudio = (item, index) => {

    if (isConnected) {
      if (!isEmpty(audioURL)) {
        //   console.log('selected audio url is', audioURL);
        SoundPlayer.playUrl(audioURL);
        this.setState({
          paused: false,
          currentPosition: 0,
          currentTime: 0,
          audioSelectedIndex: index,
        });
      }
    } else {
    }
  }

  renderItem = ({ item, indexx }) => (
    <Cell
      item={item}
      onSelected={this.selectedAudio}
      index={indexx}
      audioSelectedIndex={this.state.audioSelectedIndex}
    />
  )


                render() {
                return (
                 <View some styles>
                  <FlatList
                    style={styles.faltList}
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator
                    data={podcast}
                    extraData={this.state}
                    ItemSeparatorComponent={this.separator}
                    renderItem={this.renderItem}
                    />
                    </View>
                   );
                  }


Cell.js

export default class Cell extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { item, indexx, audioSelectedIndex } = this.props;
    return (

      <View style={styles.flatListCell}>
          <View style={styles.containerText}>
              <Text style={styles.title}>
                {item.title}
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.props.onSelected.bind(this, item)}>
            <Image
              style={styles.playPause}
              source={audioSelectedIndex === indexx ? res.images.play : res.images.pause}
            />
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        </ImageBackground>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: better solution here would be to make a media component, which has play icon, title of the song playing etc, and let each component control it's state.

Comment: But,  the problem is,  Our audio player's UI is different,  So,  I have created customized UI. So,  Can't go with media component.

Comment: yes I'm talking about a custom component.

Comment: If you have answer for this query,  Please post it in answer query. I have tried something but,  it is changing all the cells images.

Comment: I've added an answer.

Comment: Let me check,  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are destructuring `({ item, indexx })`, and renderItem doesn't pass `indexx` but `index`. Change `indexx` to `index`.

```
renderPodcastItem = ({ item, index }) => (
  <Cell
    item={item}
    onSelected={this.selectedAudio}
    index={index}
    audioSelectedIndex={this.state.audioSelectedIndex}
  />
)
```

Second mistake, you are doing this `const { item, indexx, audioSelectedIndex } = this.props;` but you are not passing `indexx` but `index` to `Cell`. In Cell component change to.

```
const { item, index, audioSelectedIndex } = this.props;
```

Third mistake you are passing `this.renderItem` to renderItem but the function is undefined.

```
renderItem={this.renderPodcastItem}
```

[DEMO](https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/playeritem)

Comment: and don't forget to pass an index to `onSelected` `onPress={this.props.onSelected.bind(this, item, index)}>`

Comment: I have edited renderItem text,  please check. Because namung convention just changed due to  privacy

Comment: And in player if I tap on pause button,  how to change that play to pause image in flatlist?

Comment: @AnilkumariOSReactNative I've added a demo to my answer.

Comment: L In your demo, Default two items playing before select item, Please check once

Comment: Thank you, But, If I tap on pause while playing from audio player, I am calling some function, Using that, How to update pause icon in flatlist? How props can work here? Any suggestions on that?

Comment: pass the index to that function and update state from there.

Comment: But, How can we update in cell class? Do we need to call again renderitem?

Comment: please don't forget to accept my answer and if you still have more questions, please create another question with the relevant code, and the SO community will help

Comment: I am checking your code, I will accept if everything fine. Thank you, Appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: @AnilkumariOSReactNative please don't ask multiple questions in one question, if you are still facing some difficulties please ask another question.

Comment: While I am printing index from   selectedAudio = (item, index) => {
 'index', { id: ’some id’,
title: ‘some title’,
summary: 'some description’,
duration: '54:09',
link: 'http://link’,
image: 'https://jpg' }

Comment: @AnilkumariOSReactNative ??

Comment: index should be number, But, Strangely it is showing array of data for that index

Comment: I don't know how you are passing the index, are you sure you are printing index?

Comment: you can always use my code, from the demo and see how I passed the index.

Comment: I am passing as I mentioned in query. It seems, Conflicting item and index. Item printing as index data, index printing as item data.     console.log('item', item);
    console.log('index', index);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195759/discussion-between-junius-l-and-anilkumar-ios-reactnative).